# How to use xpath in Selenium RC with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, xpath, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC with IE 6 and XPath locators are terribly
slow.
So I am trying to see if javascript-xpath actually speeds up things.

But could not find enough/clear documentation on how to use native x-
path libraries.

I am doing the following:

```
protected void startSelenium (String testServer, String appName, String testInBrowser){
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*" +testInBrowser, testServer+ "/"+ appName + "/");
    echo("selenium instance created:"+selenium.getClass());
    selenium.start();
    echo("selenium instance started..." + testServer + "/" + appName +"/");

    selenium.runScript("lib/javascript-xpath-latest-cmp.js");
    selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");
    selenium.allowNativeXpath("true");
}
```

This results in speed improvement of XPath locator but the
improvements are not consistent. On some runs the time taken for a
locator is halved; while sometimes its randomly high.

Am I missing any configuration step here? Would be great if someone
who has had success with this could share their views and approach.

Thanks,
Nirmal

**Solution:**

```
protected void startSelenium (String testServer, String appName, String testInBrowser){
    selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*" +testInBrowser, testServer+ "/"+ appName + "/");
    echo("selenium instance created:"+selenium.getClass());
    selenium.start();
    echo("selenium instance started..." + testServer + "/" + appName +"/");

    selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I implemented this myself and I only had to do selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath"). In my tests, the javascript xpath was about 7x faster on IE 8. Haven't really tested on anything else, but we only use it for IE.

Comment: Hi Dan,
If we do not explicitly add the script; where does the engine come from?? Does selenium already include this js?? i wasnt able to find any such evidence.

Comment: If you look at the Selenium source code, you'll see javascript-xpath-0.1.11.js is include in common\src\js\core\xpath, so I'm assuming it's pulling from that. SOMETHING is resulting in my tests going 7x faster. =)

Answer (score 0):

I have never done this but think that you may need to do something like

```
//Add the library to the page since runScript just does an eval on the JS
selenium.runScript("document.body.append(document.createElement('script')).src = 'path/to/lib');"); 
selenium.useXpathLibrary("javascript-xpath");
selenium.allowNativeXpath("true");
```

You will need to add the library to the page and then load it.

However, I would recommend using CSS Selectors instead of XPath Selectors as they are a lot faster in Selenium. You can see how to use different locator strategies [here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html). I have seen tests become at least twice as fast as the original XPath.

Comment: I am currently using CSS Selectors... but they are a bit more complicated and there are more problems when using them with IE.

Am exploring the speed improvements offered by javascript-xpath to see it they compare with CSS selectors.